# Is there an oop based image format ?

Tags: image, oop

I'm trying to find out if there is an image format that naturally supports oop constructs in different languages/platforms. So the idea is that you could create and name a symbol save the format and load it into another language. My understanding is that various UI platforms must all draw similar things like boxes and circles, provide shaders, etc. and that there ought to be some form of standard for saving this form of information ?

I'm really looking for a pointer towards some system where I could add an object, say a lightbulb, to an image, append a name and possibly other information to the object, save the entire image and pull it up in another system and only to see my new object added in as required.

I get that this may be a subjective question instead of an objective one but I do not know what you would call such a system or where to look, so I'm hoping for a buck shot of answers I can sift through.

Comment: Maybe [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) is a good starting point? Long time ago I built a small object layer on top of it for a 3D engine and it did the job.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I think the nearest analogy for what I want to do is something along the lines of what visio can do.